# Assembly to Bytes

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

My scenario - I am trying to send a Assembly File from Server to Client (via direct TCP connection). But the major problem is- how do I convert this Assembly to bytes to that it can be readily transferred?
I used following -

```
byte[] dllAsArray;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream,loCompiled.CompiledAssembly);
    dllAsArray = stream.ToArray();
}
```

But when I use -

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(dllAsArray);
```

I get an exception -

> Could not load file or assembly '165 bytes loaded from Code generator server, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   Please help!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wouldn't that just be the raw dll contents, as though you had saved it to disk? i.e. the equivalent of `File.ReadAllBytes`?

It sounds like the dll is generated - can you save it anywhere? (temp area, memory stream, etc)?

**edit** Since it seems you are using code-dom, try using `PathToAssembly` (on the compiler-results) and `File.ReadAllBytes` (or a similar streaming mechanism).

Answer (score 4):

Simply load the File via ReadAllBytes and write via WriteAllBytes. The byte[] could be transfered over the network.

```
// Transfer to byte[]
byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\ClassLibaryOne.dll");

// Write to file again
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\ClassLibaryOne.dll", data);
```

**edit**: If you use an AssemblyBuilder to create your dll, you can use .Save(fileName) to persist it to you harddrive before.

```
AssemblyBuilder a = ...
a.Save("C:\ClassLibaryTwo.dll);
```